# Proving nonnegativity of a symmetric function on a Gaussian space

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, stochastic-processes

Let $\Gamma$ be a positive symmetric function on an appropriate probability space. Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $\mathbb{R}$ which is also symmetric. Then for every $s,t\in \mathbb{R}$, $$\Gamma(s,t)=\int e^{i\xi (t-s)} \mu(d\xi).$$

In this case, how do we prove the equation below?

The text argues that if $c$ is a real function on $\mathbb{R}$ with finite support,
$$\sum_{\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}} c(s)c(t)\Gamma(s,t)=\int |\sum_{\mathbb{R}}c(s)e^{i\xi s}|^2 \mu(d\xi)\ge 0.$$

However, I can't see how to obtain the first equality above. I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: I don't understand your question, in particular what "the first equality above" means.  Does it refer to your first displayed equation?  If so, your answer is, it is a hypothesis. If it refers to your second displayed equation, the calculation relies on the real-valuedness of $c(x)$.

Comment: The term 'positive' is terribly misleading. Here it means $\sum_{_ij }c_ic_j \Gamma(s_i,s_j)\geq  0$ that is, whatever are $n$ and $ s_1,\ldots,s_n$ the matrix $(\Gamma(s_i,s_j))$ is positive semi definite.

Comment: @kimchilover I mean the equality $\sum_{\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}} c(s)c(t)\Gamma(s,t) = \int |\sum_{\mathbb{R}} c(s)e^{i\xi s}|^2 \mu(d\xi)$. I can't figure out a calculation for this given the definition of $\Gamma(s,t)$. I agree the question is poorly written, nonnegativity follows naturally from the integral form.

Comment: For complex $z$ the following holds: $|z|^2 = zz^*$.  Apply this to $z=\sum c(s)\exp(i\xi s)$.